# Как узнать открыт ли поток при использовании StreamWriter?

Tags: c#

Для записи в файл использую StreamWriter

```
StreamWriter fout = new StreamWriter(FileName);
```

Как узнать открыт ли поток?

Answer (score 2):

Если `StreamWriter` закрыт, то свойство `BaseStream` вернет `null`.

Answer (score -1):

Подозреваю если не вылетело исключение то файл открыт или создан и поток существует, можно определить спомощью try catch **finalize**.

Если ваша задача по сложнее, то
читайте все что позволяет избегать блокировок, например симофоры или мютексы, ссылки на последнии:

[офф док](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[со стороны](http://professorweb.ru/my/csharp/thread_and_files/1/1_11.php)